# Automatically restart formula given that parameter is met?

Tags: excel

I am in need of some assistance. I have a list of multiple id's in column A, column b contains data of the number of items linked to the ID. I want to generate a list of every page pertaining to each ID as follows, so i want in column C (for example) "a - Page 0001" all the way until "a - 1000" given that a had 1000 pages but then when it reaches 1000, i want it to restart from b as follows:

```
Column A   Column B   
a            1000   
b            2000   
c            1500   
d            1200   
e             700 

a - Page 0001
a - Page 0002 
a - Page 0003
a - Page 0004
… 
a - Page 1000 
b - Page 0001 
b - Page 0002 
b - Page 0003 
b - Page 0004 
… 
b - Page 0001
…
b - Page 2000 
c - Page 0001
```

I have tried using the following formula:

```
 =IF(ROW(C1)< B1+1,CONCATENATE($A$1," - Page ",TEXT(ROW(C1),"0000"),""))
```

The problem is that once it reaches 1000 I get errors (#VALUE!), firstly, I believe I have to $ the &A$1 otherwise when I drag the formula down it will just refer to the column to the left an i'll get a - Page 0001, b - page 0002, etc. Secondly, I am using the ROW function in order to generate the page numbers but I don't understand how I can force it to restart from 1 once it reaches the maximum (i.e. 1000 for a).

Comment: your table at the top where you pull the name, and number of pages,  how many rows is that table?  if its small we can do a series of nested ifs.  Are the number of pages unique?  ie does 1000 only appear once, or is there possibility that another letter could have 1000 as well?

Comment: Can we have a helper column for your table?

Comment: Hi Forward Ed, I have over 1000 ID's, and there are multiple instances of 1000, some may have only 1 page, some may have 30, some may have 1500.

Comment: OK Based on your comments I know it can be done with a helper column

Answer (score 0):

This formula will generate you list of individual pages:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(C1)-1,$C$1:$C$5,1)+1,1))&" - Page "&RIGHT("0000"&ROW(C1)-IFERROR(INDEX($C$1:$C$5,MATCH(ROW(C1)-1,$C$1:$C$5,1)),0),4),"")
```

The key to making it work is column C which is a helper formula.  In C we are going to place a running total of the number of pages.  In C1 use:

```
=SUM($B$1:$B1)
```

note the missing $ in the last address, its important that it not be there.  copy that down for the length of your table.

[image: Results]

Note the hidden rows

Comment: Hi Forward Ed, thank you for your response, this is great however, I do not have a running total for each ID, I have a list of ID's in column A, Column B tells me how many pages I have. Based on these two columns I want to generate a list that concatenates (as you have done) the ID (column a) and numbers all the way until the last number (specified in column b), then I want the row after the last one for any given ID (a - Page 1000), to be b - Page 0001. The formula you gave although is great and better than mine, I still cant get it to restart at 0001 once the last ID has reached its max.

Comment: I do not know how to do this without the use of the helper column.  The helper column that is generated with the second formula gives the break point for when to change the letter and how many pages to subtract from the row number to give the right page number for the letter you care currently dealing with. If you do not want the helper column to be seen you can put it off to the side of the page, or you could hide the column you place it in.

Comment: I am using the helper column and believe it is a great idea (I wish I had thought of this before) however it sums the number b1 and b2, then b2 and b3 and provides a running total however, I have a list of 1000 ID's, the id is in column a, the number of pages is in column b, so where I have one row telling me id a has 1000 pages, I want to generate a list of 1000 rows pertaining to ID A and its 1000 pages and once it reaches 1000, to start from b and so on.

Comment: the first formula has been update to account for formatting but it should be doing what you want.  I used a small number of pages in my example so it would be easier to see the changes from the generated list when you copy the first formula down like I did in column E.  please note I hid some of the row where the letter was not changing, I only showed the rows around where the letter changes and the numbering restarts.

Comment: Hi Forward Ed, thank you very much. I've been trying so many different ways for a couple of weeks now and had to ask on the forum and this works perfectly.